# Deleting a substring if is not a spanish word using regex

Tags: regex, substring

For example, if I have:

```
a = "aveces soñar es muy ließ y también человек"
```

I want the output to be:

```
"aveces soñar es muy y también"
```

I'm using the regex: '[^\u0000-\u007FáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ¿¡]+' to match the characters that don't belong to spanish, but I don't know how to delete the word if it contains one of those characters.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: i'm using python 3.5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex(I am trusting the unicode range provided by you):

`(?:^|\s)(?=\S*[^\u0000-\u007FáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ¿¡])\S+`

[Substitute any match with a blank string. **Click for Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/d6dSoq/4/)

**Explanation:**

- `(?:^|\s)` - matches either start of the string or a white-space
- `(?=\S*[^\u0000-\u007FáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ¿¡])` - [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if a non-spanish character is present or not
- `\S+` - In case a non-spanish character is present(checked in step 2), match 1+ occurrences of non-whitespace characters

**Python code([Generated](https://regex101.com/r/d6dSoq/4/codegen?language=python)):**

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(?:^|\s)(?=\S*[^\u0000-\u007FáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ¿¡])\S+"

test_str = "aveces soñar es muy ließ y también человек"

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

**[To see the output, Run code here](http://rextester.com/MCOJ63051)**

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)